# ASP.NET MVC4: How to return 401 from action without redirecting to login-page? (Form Authentication)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, authorization

I am currently working on an old ASP.NET MVC4 project. It is quite massive, so I'm not able to completely change huge architectural details in the given timeframe. How do I solve the following issue?

I want to return 401 from a single controller-action. I tried doing this by either

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult()
```

or

```
Response.StatusCode = 401; return null;
```

Since in the web.config Form-Authentication is enabled, I get redirected to the specified login-page. I do not want this. I just want to return 401 to the browser without taking any additional actions. The following is the passage from the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="/Login" loginUrl="/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Is this even possible to achieve my goal?

Note that I've already added the following code to the web-config:

```
 <location path="PageThatShouldReturn401">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick observation - You have your status' wrong:

- 301 - Moved Permanently
- 401 - Unauthorized

That could be affecting the behaviour you're seeing